# Creating a new ruby platform in netbeans

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I have ruby installed on my mac machine and netbeans shows that as one of the ruby platforms. I have installed some new gems on my machine with a different GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH locations so that these new gems do not interfere with the gems installed as part of the default ruby installation. Now I want to create a new ruby platform in Netbeans so that it uses the new GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME locations and not the default locations(but without installing a new version of ruby). For this netbeans asks for the location of the ruby interpreter file. On selecting the default ruby interpreter file it does not create a new platform, pointing back to the already installed platform. If I copy the interpreter file to a new location and provide it to netbeans then it does create a new platform but the name of the platform remains the same(Ruby 1.8.7-p174 in my case). In the new platform I can change the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH variables. Netbeans does not provide any mechanism to change the platform name which is quite inconvenient since its going to create confusion when switching between platforms.

My question is how can I change the platform name? Can I change it by directly editing the netbeans preferences file(in case there is no way to do this from the ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, what you are trying to do can get really complicated. Well it sounds complicated.

If in both cases you are using the same version of ruby and different gems ( even if its different versions of ruby )

You can use Ruby Version Manager rvm, and ( if necessary rvm gemsets ) . Its super-awesome.

- https://rvm.io/

Also rvm integrates with Netbeans

- https://rvm.io/integration/netbeans/